# Why sometimes Word documents decrease in size after you add more text?

Tags: microsoft-word

There are many times when I do my usual document backup (overwriting the previous one) I discover that even though I have added a fair amount of text to the newer document (and have NOT changed the formatting of existing text) it can be smaller than the older document.

Sometimes after I add about 3 thousand more words to a given document, its size can drop by 15kb compared to the previous iteration of the same document (without reducing existing images size or editing formatting).

What is the cause of this?

Comment: Are these `.doc` or `.docx` documents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The modern word file format is a set of xml files inside a zip container (go ahead, rename your `.docx` file to `.zip` and you can open the file in your favorite zip program).

If the text you are adding to the file compresses well, for example it contains a lot of repeating patterns of text or the original document was using a older version of the standard that did not use as an aggressive zip setting, the file size could end up going down due to how the file was zipped afterword.

Answer (score -2):

No one really understands the file-format for word, not even Microsoft, not even these that have reverse engineered it. There is a standard for it, but that is said to be useless.

One thing is known, that is that the modern versions are a bunch of files zipped up. Therefore the zip algorithm may do a better job next time.

Another option, it may do some sort of garbage collection: delete stuff that is no longer needed. (it is well known that people have extracted deleted text from word documents, often to the embarrassment of the author.)

Comment: This answer sounds completely ridiculous.  +1 anyway, because I think that it is true, despite Microsoft's ridiculousness.

Comment: What do you mean "no one understand it". Its a computer program isnt it? If its not understood then how was it written? How is it patched and supported? I am new to programming so I do not quite got what you said there.

Comment: No it is supposed to be a file-format (not a program), however you are partly correct. I think that word files are essentially a memory dump of the Word application. (for modern word files it is a zipped, xml of a memory dump of the word application). And it is possible for man to create a program that is to complex to understand. For a trivial example to the halting problem ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=macM_MtS_w4 )

Comment: "xml of a memory dump of the word application", no its not anything like that. it is a well formed document with published information about the specification in ISO/IEC 29500, also known as "[Office Open XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML)"

Comment: April Fools!!!!

Comment: Is this an April Fools joke? Gah now I am twice as confused.

Comment: No people think that the standard for MS office documents is an april fools joke; others think it is incompetence; still others think it is a deliberate attempt at obfuscation, vendor-lock-in, and marketing.

Comment: "If you think you understand ISO/IEC 29500, you don't understand ISO/IEC 29500."